# Is it possible to use a static IP assigned by my ISP for an offsite web server on a VPS (different ISP)?

Tags: networking, ip, windows-server-2008-r2, isp

I have a web server on a Virtual Private Server with a hosting provider. Unfortunately, they are really stingy with IP addresses and I need to run several SSL certificates on my server, so I will need a few more than I have.

I have a block of 5 static IP addresses on a business package through a different ISP and I am only using 1 of them for connectivity in the office. What I am wondering is if it is possible to use the 4 unused static IP addresses from this ISP on my VPS, which is hosted by another ISP?

The VPS (web server) is running Windows Server 2008 R2 Web Edition. If this can be done, please let me know how to configure it.

Comment: No. Data to those IPs will be routed to your office. While you might be able to forward that again it would be complex and likely **insecure**. Now what was the goal of those SSL certificates... ?

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer. Not sure what the downvote is for - it is a perfectly valid (and answerable) question.

Comment: Not my down vote. However I suspect it is due to what I described as 'it feels unclean'.

Comment: Unclean, maybe. However in a world with no more IPv4 addresses, I am looking for alternatives. Still waiting on an answer from my hosting provider whether IPv6 addresses are available yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.   Those five IPs from the other ISP (lets call this ISP-b) will be routed to your office. You can not just use them on another location and expect the rest of the world to connect to them. Instead the 'rest of the world' will attempt to reach computers via the ISP-b line to your office.

You could either run the servers in your own office, or forward all data from your office to ISP-a. That would use much more network traffic, it will increase latency, it is more complex (and hence probably less secure) and it feels unclean.

The more complex and less secure part conflicts with the likely goal of using SSL certificates.